# What does this line do in js "obj[ind++] setter = getNext;"?

Tags: javascript

This is from [John Resig's blog](https://johnresig.com/blog/re-securing-json/) about JSON responses being stolen:

> ```
> // From Joe Walker
> function Array() {
>   var obj = this;
>   var ind = 0;
>   var getNext = function(x) {
>     obj[ind++] setter = getNext;
>     if (x) alert("Data stolen from array: " + x.toString());
>   };
>   this[ind++] setter = getNext;
> }
> var a = ["private stuff"];
> // alert("Data stolen from array: private stuff");
> ```

As the question title states I can't figure out `obj[ind++] setter = getNext;`

Comment: that's a 10 year old blog

Comment: @Jaromanda I realize that. Do you know what the syntax means even if the bug has been fixed?

Comment: I don't think that's valid syntax

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, confusing, no?

Comment: that's why I don't read 10 year old blogs by self described experts :p and as he's the original author of jQuery, he has my admiration for creating the library that make it possible to forget about browser differences ... for this same reason I despise his work for keeping Internet Exploder alive

Comment: @user5389726598465 looks like its old syntax. Checjk comments http://incompleteness.me/blog/2007/03/05/json-is-not-as-safe-as-people-think-it-is/

Comment: @gvmani Douglas Crockford commented and didn't say anything about the syntax so at some point in the past it meant something but what!

Comment: @gvmani ah, I didn't see the comment you were talking about. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's just pseudo code, javascript never had such syntax.
Although javascript does have some form of getter/setter now, it didn't back in these days.

Comment: `It's just pseudo code, javascript never had such syntax` - don't be so sure

Comment: I'm really confident it never had. Can you point to a ressource that says otherwise ?

Comment: https://whereswalden.com/tag/setter/ ... search for `property getter` (do you know how hard it is to find documentation for a spidermonkey only syntax deprecated over 10 years ago :p )

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't knew about that, even though I was writing a lot of JS at that time. Technically it has never been a part of the language nor any draft, it's a mozilla only experiment.